# Reset a Marketo Form upon submission

Tags: forms, marketo

I have an embedded Marketo form I am using on my site.

When I click `submit` I want the form to reset to its original state.

What do I need to add to my code for this, and better yet where can I find this in the Marketo documentation?

Here's my current code

```html
<script src="//app-sjg.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm"></form>
<script>
  MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjg.marketo.com", "819-OWT-537", 1404);
</script>
<script>
  MktoForms2.whenReady(function (form){
    form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl){
      $('#confirmform').modal('show');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Marketo [Form object](http://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/forms/api-reference/) does not have the reset functionality, but luckily enough, javascript has such a native [`.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method on the HTML form elements. This `.reset()` method will restore a form element’s default values.

Having said that, the only thing to do within the `.onSuccess()` callback is to grab the HTML form. Calling the `.getFormElem()` method of the Marketo Form object, will give us the jQuery wrapped form element, so with `form.getFormElem()[0]` finally we get the form node, on which we can call `.reset()`.

Here is the sample code:

```js
<script src="//app-lon06.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm"></form>
<script>
// The fourth argument of the `.loadForm()` can be used as an onReady callback.
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjg.marketo.com", "819-OWT-537", 1404, function(form) {
    form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl){
        // $('#confirmform').modal('show');
        console.log(form);
        // .getFormElem() returns the jQuery wrapped form element
        var formElement = form.getFormElem()[0];
        // .reset() is a native javascript method.
        formElement.reset();

        // If boolean `false` is returned then the visitor 
        // will NOT be forwarded to the follow up page!
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Note: the good thing is, that all the important hidden fields (e.g.: *formid* and *munchkinId*) will remain intact.